# How to disable the default keyboard in windows phone

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, textbox

I don't the default keyboard to popup when giving focus to the textbox in windows phone. Didn't find a way to disable the keyboard. Is there a way to disable it ?

I also tried to extend the textbox and in `OnFocus` removed the `base.OnFocus()`, which effectively removes the keyboard. But all other textbox features are also not working. Any pointers regarding this will be really helpful.

Thanks
Kumaran

Comment: Why would you disable input for a data entry control?

Comment: Want to give a feature to input in a lang which is not supported in windows phone.

Comment: There is no other easy way to do it other than rewriting custom textbox control.